# Query the Wordpress database to get data together with replaced information

Tags: query, mysql

sorry for cross-posting: I posted a similar question on StackOverflow but I received no attention (my fault, for sure).

I need to query a Wordpress database.

The first table is `wp_posts`: from this table I need to retrieve the `ID` and the `post_content` where the post_title is `“A”`, `“B”` or `“C”`. This is of course fairly easy:

```
SELECT ID,post_content FROM `wp_posts` 
WHERE post_title IN ("A","B","C") and post_type = "plugin_is_writing_this_record"
```

`post_type` is necessary here because only a particular Wordpress plugin writes records using that post_type.

Problem is that the same plugin (a plugin used to send forms) replaces with a 0 a vital information for me: the `post_author`, that in `wp_posts` is generally **the `id` of the user who created the post**, **is NOT the id of the user who posted the form, but the id of the user who created the post where the form is located**. I need to retrieve the id of the user who posted the form.

Using the `ID` of the post in `wp_posts`, I could get the `email` of the user from the table `wp_postmeta`.

If you query this last table this way:

`SELECT * FROM`wp_postmeta`WHERE post_id = 277125` (*)

you get data this way (I cut down data a little):

```
meta_id | post_id | meta_key            | meta_value
----------------------------------------------------------
3       | 277125  | _from_email         | from@mail.com
4       | 277125  | _field_your-surname | Surname
5       | 277125  | other_meta_key      | otherdata
6       | 277125  | ...                 | ...
```

At this point, I know `_from_email` meta value is related to the mail of the user who posted the form (I need to retrieve even other meta_keys from this table but this one is functional to the query and to this question).

The table that contains the `ID` I need and the email of the user is of course `wp_users`, a third table.

Is it possible in a single query over the three tables at once to retrieve the data I need? I tried some JOINS but I couldn't get them working properly. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This query worked for me. I had to reverse it, starting at the user and then matching the post ID. You would need to replace the value of wp_posts.ID of course.

```
SELECT wp_users.ID
FROM wp_users
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_postmeta.meta_value = wp_users.user_email AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_from_email' 
LEFT JOIN wp_posts ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id AND wp_posts.ID = 2
```

Comment: Why `AND wp_posts.ID = 2`?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I don't need a particular post, but any post

Comment: Then you can remove the last AND. At the end of the day, what data exactly do you need from each table?

Comment: post_content, post_date and post_id from wp_posts, any meta_key/meta_value in wp_postmeta, id of the user from wp_users. Still not sure if I should query only, eg., latest 24 hours, but this is a detail